# No values shown in histogram with "mouse-over"

Tags: histograms, tooltip

Today I experienced a strange behavior in a histogram I made. Here a MWE:
Given a set of points:

```
pts = RandomReal[1, {1000, 2}];
```

and a helper function which does as it is named:

```
ClearAll[uniqueTuples];
uniqueTuples[list_List]:=Module[{n=Length[list]},
Flatten[Table[{list[[i]],list[[i+j]]},{i,1,n},{j,1,n-i}],1]
]
```

then I made two histograms and displayed them in a `GraphicsRow`

```
Block[{dist, h1, h2},
 dist = EuclideanDistance @@@ (uniqueTuples[pts]);
 h1 = Histogram[dist, PlotLabel -> "Euclidian-distance"];
 dist = ManhattanDistance[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ (uniqueTuples[pts]);
 h2 = Histogram[dist, PlotLabel -> "Manhatten-distance"];
 GraphicsRow[{h1, h2}, ImageSize -> Large]
 ]
```

When I point over the right histogram the values of the bars are shown, but not for the left histogram:

[image]
I do not understand why this is so (maybe it has a simple reason, but at the moment I do not understand this).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding the option `LabelingFunction -> Tooltip` fixes the problem.

If the number of bins exceeds 25, `LabelingFunction` option value is set to `None`. You can see the code behind `` Charting`iHistogram `` (which is called by `Histogram`) after clearing its `Protected` and `ReadProtected` attributes. The relevant part of the code is:

```
If[System`HistogramDump`perfgoal===Speed||System`HistogramDump`numberOfBins > 25,
 If[System`HistogramDump`highlight === Automatic, 
   System`HistogramDump`highlight = None];
 If[System`HistogramDump`labelingfunction === Automatic, 
   System`HistogramDump`labelingfunction = None]]
```