# How to draw bin edges?

Tags: plotting, graphics, histograms

I would like to show the edges on the following produced histogram:

This works as expected in terms of edges:

```
Histogram3D[
{data2000[[1]]},
ImageSize -> 1400,
ChartStyle -> Opacity[1],
ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[{Black, AbsoluteThickness[1]}],
ColorFunction -> Function[{height}, ColorData["Rainbow"][height]]]
```

When I add a another dataset, edges disappear:

```
Histogram3D[
{data2000[[1]], data1950[[1]]},
ImageSize -> 1400,
ChartStyle -> Opacity[1],
ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[{Black, AbsoluteThickness[1]}],
ColorFunction -> Function[{height}, ColorData["Rainbow"][height]]]
```

How can I get edges even when adding multiple datasets?

*Updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by the hard-coded threshold on the number of bins in the function `` Charting`iHistogram3D ``: If the number of bins in either direction is equal to or greater than 50, the `EdgeForm` directive is reset to `EdgeForm[]` :

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomReal[100, {400, 2}];

Row[Histogram3D[data, {{"Raw", #}, {"Raw", 40}}, "Count", 
    PlotLabel -> Style[{Row[{{"Raw", #}, {"Raw", 40}}, ", "]}, 16], 
    ImageSize -> 400, 
    ChartBaseStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[{Red, AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}]], 
    Boxed -> False, Axes -> False] & /@ {40, 66}]
```

[image]

A simple work-around is to post-process the `Histogram3D` output to inject the desired styling:

```
Histogram3D[data, {{"Raw", 66}, {"Raw", 40}}, "Count", 
   ImageSize -> 700, 
   ChartBaseStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[{Red, AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}]]] /. 
 EdgeForm[___] -> Directive[EdgeForm[{Red, AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}]]
```

[image]

**Related Q/As:**

- [No values shown in histogram with
  “mouse-over”](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/183014/125)

Comment: You're da boss. THx

Answer (score 0):

Your thickness is too high.

```
Histogram3D[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {500, 2}], 
 ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[{Red, AbsoluteThickness[.01]}]]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {200, 2}]; histo = 
 Histogram3D[data1, {{"Raw", 50}, {"Raw", 40}}, "Count", 
  ChartBaseStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[Red], Thickness[0.000001]]]` ?

Comment: `data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {200, 2}]; histo = 
 Histogram3D[data1, {{"Raw", 49}, {"Raw", 40}}, "Count", 
  ChartBaseStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[Red], Thickness[10000000]]]`  ??

Comment: @cvgmt use AbsoluteThickness[.01]

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't solve the prob